# PHP Where if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with this. I have two types of images being saved, but not required.

I want to display the "rendered" image by default, but if no "rendered" image, display the "brochure" image instead.

Right now it is set to display a nopic.png image if no rendered image, but I want to replace the nopic image with a brochure image. There will always be a brochure image, so the nopic image is not needed.

Here is current code...

```
$query->select('*, c.alias')
        ->from('#__iproperty_catfp_img i')
        ->join('inner','#__iproperty_categories c ON c.id = i.cat_id')
        ->where('i.fp_id = '.(int)$fb_id)
        ->where('i.cat_id = '.(int)$cat_id)
        ->where('i.img_type = "rendering"')
        ->order('i.id DESC');
    $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);

    $thumb         = $db->loadObject();

    $root_path     = ($rel_path) ? JURI::root(true) : substr(JURI::root(), 0, -1);




    //add appropriate path to thumbnail file

    if ( $thumb ) {// if rendered image

        $thumbnail = $root_path."/fpimagegallery/$thumb->alias/$thumb->img_type/$thumb->file_name";
    } 

    else { //no rendered image, show brochure image
        $path      = $root_path.$settings->fpimgpath;
        $thumbnail = $path.'nopic.png';
    }
```

Here is what I have tried but no images are displaying...

```
$query->select('*, c.alias')
        ->from('#__iproperty_catfp_img i')
        ->join('inner','#__iproperty_categories c ON c.id = i.cat_id')
        ->where('i.fp_id = '.(int)$fb_id)
        ->where('i.cat_id = '.(int)$cat_id)
        ->where('i.img_type = "rendering" AND "brochure"')
        ->order('i.id DESC');
    $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);

    $thumb         = $db->loadObject();

    $root_path     = ($rel_path) ? JURI::root(true) : substr(JURI::root(), 0, -1);




    //add appropriate path to thumbnail file

    if ( $thumb ) {// if rendered image

        $thumbnail = $root_path."/fpimagegallery/$thumb->alias/$thumb->rendering/$thumb->file_name";
    } 

    else { //if no rendered image, show brochure image
        $thumbnail = $root_path."/fpimagegallery/$thumb->alias/$thumb->brochure/$thumb->file_name";
    }
```

I'm think if I word the Where statement correctly, I can get this to work?

Here is what is in the table... 
[table screenshot http://expressville.com/fp_images_ss.png](http://expressville.com/fp_images_ss.png)

And actually as far as the file path is concerned... the code could be even changed like this. All the folder have a rendering and brochure subfolders with the appropriate images located in each.

```
if ( $thumb ) {
$thumbnail = $root_path . "/fpimagegallery/{$thumb->alias}/rendering/{$thumb->file_name}";
}     
else {
$thumbnail = $root_path . "/fpimagegallery/{$thumb->alias}/brochure/{$thumb->file_name}";
```

}

Comment: is it specified in the browser itself whether the image is `rendered` or `brochure`?

Comment: The rendering and brochure are just image types. When an image is saved in the db, it is labeled as either rendering or brochure in the img_type field. See above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation as your requirement i.e as follows.

**I have a table emp1 with schema as follows:**

```
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sal      | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cat_name | varchar(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**and with following data:**

```
+------+------+----------+
| name | sal  | cat_name |
+------+------+----------+
| c    | 4002 | cat2     |
| d    | 7001 | cat2     |
| a    | 1234 | cat1     |
| b    | 2235 | cat2     |
| c    | 1234 | cat1     |
| a    | 2235 | cat2     |
| e    | 1234 | cat1     |
+------+------+----------+
```

**And I had the following requirement:**

- **select those `name` and `sal` from those tuples where there is cat_name `'cat1'` even if that `name` also exists in another tuple with `cat_name` `'cat2'` as well as(i.e. `UNION`) select those `name` and `sal` which has only `'cat2'` as the `cat_name` but not `'cat1'`**.

So in my case `'cat1'` is similar to `'rendering'` and `'cat2'` is similar to `'brochure'` in your case.

I had to use the following SQL:

```
select name, sal from emp1 where name in (select name from emp1 group by name having 
count(cat_name)=1)
union
select name, sal from emp1 where (name, sal, cat_name) in
(select * from emp1 where cat_name='cat1');
```

**O/P**

```
+------+------+
| name | sal  |
+------+------+
| d    | 7001 |
| b    | 2235 |
| e    | 1234 |
| a    | 1234 |
| c    | 1234 |
+------+------+
```

Here `'d'`, `'b'`, `'e'` have only one `cat_name` each hence those were included and `'a'` and `'c'` have both the `cat_name` i.e `'cat1'` and `'cat2'`; hence the records of `'a'` and `'c'` with `cat_name` as `'cat1'` were included.

*As I am not fluent with the syntax you have used in **php** I can't give you a complete solution. Hope this will be helpful.*